# Is it possible for me to put a default url for the web app icon on iPhone?

Tags: html, iphone-standalone-web-app

I am creating a web app and when I save it to the screen, it only saves to the url I am on. Is it possible to alter the HTML so that if its being saved to the homescreen, it goes to a specific url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to change the URL that is linked to the web app bookmark.

A workaround could be to redirect the user to the desired page. You can **for example** store client information on the server (cookies/session) or device ([localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)). So when the user visits your site you can redirect to the homepage if the client device has no session or if some localStorage value is not set.